# Making an empy Sudoku solver on C

Tags: c

So i got an assignment in class to make an empty sudoku that every time creates a random solution of 9x9.
I got to the point where i get different number each row and column but not on every 3x3 matrix and i cannot figure out how to go on from here.
We didnt learn recursion yet and can use only the libraries listed in the code.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NINE 9
#define ONE 1

void solve_sudoku(int board[9][9])
{
    srand(time(0));
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0;i <= NINE;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < NINE;j++)
        {
            board[i][j] =(rand() % NINE)+ONE;
            for (int k = 0;k < 9;k++)
            {
                int clone_i = i;
                int clone_j = j;
                while (board[i][k] == board[i][j])
                {
                    if (j == k)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                    board[i][j] = (rand() % NINE) + ONE;
                    k = 0;
                }
                while(board[k][j]==board[i][j])
                    {
                    if (i == k)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                        board[i][j] = (rand() % NINE) + ONE;
                        k = 0;
                    }
                if (count > 300 || (board[i][j] == board[i][k] && j != k))
                {
                    for (int i = clone_i;i < clone_i + 1;i++)
                        for (int l = 0;l < 9;l++)
                        {
                            board[i][l] = 0;
                        }
                    count = 0;
                    k = 0;
                    j = 0;
                }
                
                }
            }
        }
    }



void print_sudoku(int board[][9])
{
    printf("The soduko solution is: \n");
    for (int i = 0;i < NINE;i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0;k < NINE;k++)
        {
            printf("%d ", board[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int sud[9][9] = { 0 };
    int matrix_size = 9;
    solve_sudoku(sud);
    print_sudoku(sud);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So that would be a Sudoku *generator*, yes?

Comment: Suggestion: prefer, for example, `#define LOW_VALUE 1` and `#define HIGH_VALUE 9`. The macros `ONE` and `NINE` are either `1` and `9` respectively (and have no real reason to exist) or **are very badly chosen names** ... `#define ONE 4` `#define NINE 7` **Ugh!** `#define LOW_VALUE 4` and `#define HIGH_VALUE 7` is much better

Comment: yes @JohnBollinger

Comment: _"We didnt learn recursion yet"_ does this mean that you are not allowd to use recursion?

Comment: @Ackdari yes, we are not allowed to use them yet in this problem

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67706840/4386427

Answer (score 2):

I take you to mean that you need to generate random 9 x 9 grids of digits that meet the Sudoku criterion that each row, column and block contains all nine digits.  In that case, you are going about it a very difficult way. Perhaps that was inspired by viewing the program as a solver, instead of what it really needs to be: a generator.

Consider that it is easy to write down at least one valid Sudoku algorithmically:

```
 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 | 1 2 3
 7 8 9 | 1 2 3 | 4 5 6
 ------+-------+------
 2 3 4 | 5 6 7 | 8 9 1
 5 6 7 | 8 9 1 | 2 3 4
 8 9 1 | 2 3 4 | 5 6 7
 ------+-------+------
 3 4 5 | 6 7 8 | 9 1 2
 6 7 8 | 9 1 2 | 3 4 5
 9 1 2 | 3 4 5 | 6 7 8
```

Now consider that you can always transform one valid Sudoku into a different one by swapping two rows or two columns such that no entries move from one block to another.  For example, you can swap the first row with the third, or the fifth column with the sixth.  If you perform a bunch of random swaps of that kind on a valid starting Sudoku then you will end up with a random grid that meets the Sudoku criteria.

Note that it is a different story if you need to produce only Sudoku that can be solved by deduction alone, without trial & error.  For that you probably do need a solver-based approach, but that starts with a *bona fide* solver, and nothing in your code is anything like that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would you suggest to start the problem over? and if do, in what way should i approach the problem? would love to see an example.

Comment: @GuyMovshovich, this answer already proposes an alternative, probably more productive way to approach the problem.  Inasmuch as it does so, yes, I am recommending that you start over.

Comment: This will generate valid solutions all the time but it's too simple. All sodukos generated will have a common pattern.

Comment: Example: The vertical numbers `3 6 9` in a 3x3 block will always be together. They can be `3 6 9`, `3, 9 6`, `6 3 9`, `6 9 3`, `9 3 6` or `9 6 3` but they will always stay together.

Comment: @4386427, as far as I am aware, the exercise does not place a constraint against the generated grids having a common pattern.  Nevertheless, I do not accept your analysis.  Although I do not claim that *all* possible Sudoku grids can be generated this way, I am confident that performing a sufficient number of random swaps such as I described (along both directions) will produce grids with no discernable pattern.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I didn't say it's illegal. In fact I did say that the code would generate **legal** solution. My point is just that a generate that always generates the sódukos from the same group isn't that "fun". BTW: See my deleted solution. Different approach but my code did the same, i.e. all generated solutions belonged to the same group.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "... discernable pattern" Well, that's the problem. For all sodukos generated by this code there is a pattern. Once I known where to place e.g. the number 3 in a 3x3 block, I know that numbers 6 and 9 has to go in the same column of that 3x3 block. No matter how many times you swap, they stay together.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you are interrested, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67706840/4386427