# How to fill an empty sudoku board in C

Tags: c

I got an assignment to write a program that fills an empty sudoku board and prints it out.

The tools that we have are only functions, arrays and pointers. No recursion, no search and sort algorithms to improve the time complexity.

So far I thought to use two dimension array for the board and go over every row in a nested "for" loop.

Every time I fetch a number with a random function and check a row, a column and a square (3X3), and if all of them pass then I fill the number.

My problem is that, that way it takes the code a very long time to solve, and I don't know if I'm doing it right. I didn't see a solution of my code yet, even after leaving it to run more than 5 minutes. I thought maybe somehow to use a histogram of numbers from 1-9 that maps which numbers already used to somehow change the use of fetching random numbers, but I'm not really sure how to use it and if it's even right to do so. Basically I'm stuck.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MATRIX_SIZE 9
#define MAX_NUM 9

void solve_sudoku(int board[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]);
void print_sudoku(int board[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE]);
int rowCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int row);
int columnCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int row);
int squareCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int row, int col);
int giveNum(void);

void main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int board[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
    /*{ 
    0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,
    0,6,8,0,0,0,5,0,0,
    0,2,0,0,0,0,0,7,6,
    6,0,0,0,0,0,8,9,0,
    0,0,5,2,6,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,9,0,0,1,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,7,0,5,0,
    0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
    0,0,0,0,5,1,4,0,0
    };*/
    for (int row = 0; row < MATRIX_SIZE; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < MATRIX_SIZE; col++)
            board[row][col] = -1;
    solve_sudoku(board);
    print_sudoku(board);
}

void solve_sudoku(int board[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE])
{
    int rowCh, colCh, sqrCh, num, square = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < MATRIX_SIZE; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < MATRIX_SIZE; col++)
        {
            if (square > 2)
                square = 0;
            while(1)
            {
                num = giveNum();
                rowCh = rowCheck(num, board, row, col);
                if (!rowCh)
                    continue;
                colCh = columnCheck(num, board, row, col);
                if (!colCh)
                    continue;
                sqrCh = squareCheck(num, board, row, col-square);
                if (!sqrCh)
                    continue;
                break;
            } //while (!rowCh || !colCh || !sqrCh);
            square++;
            board[row][col] = num;
        }
    }
}

void print_sudoku(int board[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE])
{
    printf("Sudoku solution:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
            printf("%d  ", board[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int giveNum(void)
{
    int num = rand() % MATRIX_SIZE + 1;
    return num;
}

int rowCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < MATRIX_SIZE; col++)
    {
        if (num == board[row][col])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int columnCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int col)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < MATRIX_SIZE; row++)
    {
        if (num == board[row][col])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int squareCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int row, int col)
{
    for (int i = row; i < row + sqrt(MATRIX_SIZE); i++)
        for (int j = col; j < col + sqrt(MATRIX_SIZE); j++)
            if (board[i][j] == num)
                return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the values of your matrix?  I only see everything set to -1.

Comment: You should be able to replace the `sqrt(MATRIX_SIZE)` calls with a constant fairly easily (in case the compiler doesn't optimize the calls away).

Comment: hmmm.... `int rowCheck(int num, int board[][MATRIX_SIZE], int row)` and called like `rowCh = rowCheck(num, board, row, col);` hmmmm

Comment: One thing you could do for each row is fill in an array with the numbers 1 to MATRIX_SIZE in order. Do a random "Fischer-Yates Shuffle" on the array, and check each one in turn. When a suitable number is found, add it to the board and mark it as used somehow, either by replacing it with -1 or by swapping it with another element of the array, partioning it into a "used" and an "unused" section.

Comment: I know I answered this same question from a different user (and with different code) just yesterday.  Yes, here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67687165/2402272. My answer there applies here, too; it boils down to the fact that you don't need a Sudoku solver to generate valid Sudoku grids if you have no constraints other than the Sudoku condition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , Yes, Thank you, it appears that we are from the same class :)

Comment: I so much like the approach that I consider this a duplicate. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making an empy Sudoku solver on C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67687165/making-an-empy-sudoku-solver-on-c)

Comment: As I understood the assignment, the goal is to try to generate a sudoku from scratch, and not to take a valid one and just swap rows and columns. So Johns Bollinger suggestion to the problem isn't the case (I hope that I understood correctly his suggestion). So my problem is still open. I need time to sit and think on it.

Comment: Please define the difference between "making from scratch" and "filling known, followed by swapping" which you need taken care of. I do not see one. But I confirm that if there is a relevant difference the answer might not be applicable. In that case please point out how this question is different from that one. I.e. why this one is not a duplicate question of that one.

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain, We got an assignment that asked us to fill an empty board, so the solver need some how to generate from nothing a solution, without a human pre- interference. As I see it, if you give a correct board from the beginning, you changed the conditions and terms of the assignment, and the solution will not be generic. So this question might be the same assignment as the other one because it's just what it is, however the solutions and comments that are provided are not answer the question.

Comment: @VR_p, if you are concerned with whether particular implementation details fulfill the requirements of the assignment then you should certainly discuss the matter with your instructor rather than with us.  Personally, however, I do not see the distinction you are trying to draw.

Comment: In any case, I will make an observation here that I also made on the other question: if you want to use a solver-based approach then you need a a functional and efficient solver.  Yours is not one.  It is highly likely to get stuck, and any run that actually succeeds is likely to take a very long time.  A successful solver needs to rely primarily on deduction, falling back to trial & error only as a last resort, and it needs to implement backtracking for trial & error steps that don't pan out.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt that you will have much luck with a pure random approach. There are so many combinations so that chance of hitting a valid solution is very little. Instead you'll most likely end in a dead-lock where there is no valid number to put in current position... then you just have an endless loop.

Anyway... here is a bug:

For the `squareCheck` function to work, it's required that `col` and `row` identifies the upper-left corner. For `col` you ensure that using `square` but for `row` you don't.

In other words, your check isn't correct.

Instead of using "the `square` method" consider to put these lines in the start of the function:

```
row = row - (row % 3);
col = col - (col % 3);
```

Comment: Thank you  everyone for help, I will try all your suggestions

Comment: Thank you for noticing me for the incorrect square Check.

Comment: I'm still left with the main problem, how to generate numbers and fill them without the fact that it can take infinite time. I'm sure that the problem needs to be solved randomly, to be generic. The "Fischer-Yates Shuffle" sounds as a good solution, but I don't know how to create it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to generate a random suduko.

```
// Check that no number 1..9 is present twice in a column
int colok(int s[][9])
{
  for (int col=0; col<9; ++col)
  {
    for (int n=1; n<=9; ++n)
    {
      int cnt = 0;
      for (int i=0; i<9; ++i)
      {
        if (s[i][col] == n)
        {
          if (cnt > 0) return 0;
          cnt = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

// Check that no number 1..9 is present twice in a 3x3 block
int blockok(int s[][9])
{
  for (int row=0; row<9; row += 3)
  {
    for (int col=0; col<9; col +=3)
    {
      for (int n=1; n<=9; ++n)
      {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        {
          for (int j=0; j<3; ++j)
          {
            if (s[i + row][j + col] == n)
            {
              if (cnt > 0) return 0;
              cnt = 1;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

void p(int s[][9])
{
  for (int i=0; i<9; ++i)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
      printf("%d ", s[i][j]);
    }
    puts("");
  }
}

#define MAX_LOOP 10000000

void makerow(int s[][9], int r)
{
  int loops = 0;
  while(1)
  {
    ++loops;

    // FY Shuffle row (this ensures that rows are always valid)
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int max = 8;
    while(max)
    {
      int t = rand() % (max + 1);
      int tmp = a[t];
      a[t] = a[max];
      a[max] = tmp;
      --max;
    }

    // Save row
    for (int i=0; i<9; ++i)
    {
      s[r][i] = a[i];
    }

    // Check whether it's valid
    if (colok(s) && blockok(s))
    {
      // It's valid so stop here
      break;
    }

    // Stop if too many loops
    if (loops > MAX_LOOP)
    {
      puts("I'm so tired...");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  printf("loops %d\n", loops);
}

int main(void)
{
  srand((int)time(0));
  int s[9][9] = { 0 };

  for (int i=0; i<9; ++i)
  {
    printf("Make row %d\n", i);
    makerow(s, i);
  }
  p(s);

  return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
Make row 0
loops 1
Make row 1
loops 27
Make row 2
loops 1090
Make row 3
loops 3
Make row 4
loops 1019
Make row 5
loops 5521
Make row 6
loops 96
Make row 7
loops 66727
Make row 8
loops 498687
7 5 2 4 6 8 3 1 9 
3 4 6 9 1 7 8 2 5 
8 1 9 3 2 5 7 6 4 
9 6 3 8 7 4 2 5 1 
1 8 5 2 9 3 6 4 7 
2 7 4 1 5 6 9 8 3 
6 9 7 5 4 2 1 3 8 
5 2 8 7 3 1 4 9 6 
4 3 1 6 8 9 5 7 2
```

**But notice...** it happens that no solution can be generated.. then the output is:

```
Make row 0
loops 1
Make row 1
loops 37
Make row 2
loops 2957
Make row 3
loops 16
Make row 4
loops 2253
Make row 5
I'm so tired...
```

Comment: It's certainly better than the OP's cell-by-cell random approach, but as you observe, it's not reliable.  I think you recognize, too, that if you took the loop iteration limit out then it would be susceptible to running indefinitely instead of failing, just as the OP's is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Exactly... endless loop without the "stop" conditions. It's like 1 out of 6 times, it fails so I could probably just implement a complete "retry-from-start" when it fails but I'll leave that to OP. In general when it find a solution it takes 0.1 - 0.2 sec

Answer (score 0):

There's a loop `while(1)` where you pick a random number and determine if it is valid in the current position.
It's quite possible to get to a dead end here.
You can have easily filled in numbers that while valid individually leave the puzzle insoluble.

You need some method of backtracking if you get 'stuck' or detecting that it will get stuck.

The 'common' approach is to hold a 9x9 matrix of sets holding a subset of 1-9 which are the untried values. When a value is set (at start) or tried (during solve) you check the constraints and remove the value being tried from its column, row and square.

Start with a 9x9 grid all cells initialised to the full range [1-9].
If you set a cell to (say) 5 remove 5 from all cells in that column, row and sub-square.

If that leaves any cell with the empty set, the puzzle is insoluble.

When solving only pick from the set of 'remaining possible values' rather than rand [1-9].

However it still may be that a trial makes the puzzle insoluble and needs to go back a cell (or more) to come forward again.

The easy way to do that would be recursion. But that's ruled out by the Exercise.
So it looks like some kind of Undo stack is required.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid recursion you can try to navigate the solution space by levels. That requires a Queue, in which you add the next possible states from a given one (just extracted from the queue) and you mark the already visited ones (e.g. with the selected numbers)  In this way you only build a single loop (no nested loops required) and you can generate all the possible solutions (but you can stop at the first that just generates a valid position)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your responses. There is an update: I found a bug that made me a lot of problems, The bug was that I defined : columnCheck function that receives variable row and I called the function this way: "  columnCheck(num, board, row, col); ", so the bug is that in the definition I need to give only 3 arguments, when I called the function accidently with 4 and also gave the columCheck the row instead the column. Also rowCheck was called with 4 arguments instead of 3 as defined. Can someone explain why the debugger didn't warn  me about that ?
Also I changed the giveNum() function to this one:

```
    int giveNum(void)
{
    int static num = 1;
    if (num > 9)
        num = 1;
    return num++;
}
```

Now it's not random but it fills the sudoku.
Since a lot of people asked the instructor how to do it, he replied that this kind of solution will be fine for now, However I will take the challenge to solve it with your suggestions.